# Crystal Report dynamic datasource not creating report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have Googled on this subject and I have coded as per what I saw, but the CrystalReportViewer is empty and I am not getting any errors. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Below is all of my code.

```
strSQL = "select * from MMM_vw_Rpt_Summary where BudgetID = " & Master.lblBudgetIDText
ds = CreateDataset(strSQL, "cnn_rcg_mmm", "dt_Summary")
CreateSummary(ds)

Public Shared Function CreateDataset(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal strCNN As String, ByVal strTable As String) As DataSet
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strCNN).ConnectionString
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim strReturn As String
    strReturn = ""

    Try
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(strConnString)
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, con)
            con.Open()
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New dsLifeBudget

            da.Fill(ds, strTable)

            Return ds
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        strReturn = ex.Message
    End Try
End Function

Protected Sub CreateSummary(ByVal ds As DataSet)
    Dim strReportPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/LB_Summary.rpt")
    Dim cr As New ReportDocument
    Dim strError As String = ""

    Master.HideMsg()

    'Verify the path to the Crystal Report's .RPT file
    If Not IO.File.Exists(strReportPath) Then
        Throw (New Exception("Unable to locate report file:" & vbCrLf & strReportPath))
        strError = "Unable to locate report file:  " & strReportPath
        Master.txtMsgText = "Error creating Summary - " & strError
        Master.txtMsgVisible(True)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    crLifeBudget.HasDrillUpButton = False
    crLifeBudget.Height = "300px"
    crLifeBudget.Width = "500px"

    'Load the Crystal report's .RPT file and pass in the DataTable
    cr.Load(strReportPath)
    cr.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("dt_Summary"))
    crLifeBudget.ReportSource = cr
    crLifeBudget.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Eddi Rae

Comment: Have you confirmed that your dataset contains data?

Comment: Yes.  The database does have data.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring the following, It could solve the problem since your code lacks the`crLifeBudget.refresh()` line.

[Crystal Reports empty when printed during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62787124/12419718)

Comment: crLifeBudget only has the command for RefreshReport.  I added the cr.refresh after the loading of the dataset and I am still not getting any report to display

Comment: Just for clarification. How did u design the report?. Did u made the report by dragging table fields to the report?. How did u made the connection at design time?. Do u have a line something like below anywhere in your project? crLifeBudget.SetDatabaseLogon("user, dbPwd). If you did not design the report in design view, that means it's a blank page. In that case either u have to design the report by dragging the relevant fields to the report or you will have to write code to display the Records at run time. looks like you haven't  designed the report either throug design view or programmatical

Comment: Without seeing the whole project, can't say the exact problem. But, it looks like you are loading a blank report or the dataset that u created at run time is not linked to the report. Usually, report will take the data from its original connection. If the original report does not have a connection, then definitely it'll be a blank report. If you can post a screenshot of the report design, it'll be easier for us to understand.

Comment: I created my XSD first and then created the Crystal Report using the XSD.
I add my data into the XSD by creating a dataset and then load into report

Comment: Here is the creation
                    strSQL = "select * from MMM_vw_Rpt_Summary where BudgetID = " & Master.lblBudgetIDText
                    ds = CreateDataset(strSQL, "cnn_rcg_mmm", "dt_Summary")
                    If ds.Tables("dt_Summary").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        CreateSummary(ds)
                    Else
                        Master.HideMsg()
                        Master.txtMsgText = "No records found For budget " & lblBudgetName.Text
                        Master.txtMsgVisible(True)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

Comment: Here is the Load
        Dim cr As New ReportDocument
        crLifeBudget.HasDrillUpButton = False
        crLifeBudget.Height = 300
        crLifeBudget.Width = 500


        'Load the Crystal report's .RPT file and pass in the DataTable
        cr.Load(strReportPath)
        cr.SetDataSource(ds)
        cr.Refresh()

        crLifeBudget.ReportSource = cr
        crLifeBudget.RefreshReport()

Comment: I'm not sure whether you have done this already. What I mean earlier is either you have to manually insert the reports fields in crystal report design view or you have to write some code to pass the values from data set to report.Just showing the report source to the report will not be enough to show the data. So far,  I didn't see any code written to pass values from data set to report. Following is a sample code that passes values to a report. But prior to passing values using code, you have to insert and design the report manually.

Comment: start of sample code******** crepDailSalSum.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", dbPwd)
                    crepDailSalSum.RecordSelectionFormula = "{TB_SALES.added_date} >=#" & dtpFrom.Value & "# AND " & "{TB_SALES.added_date} <=#" & dtpTo.Value & "#"
                    crepDailSalSum.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = shopName & " - " & shopLocation
                    crepDailSalSum.SummaryInfo.ReportComments = (dtpFrom.Value & " - " & dtpTo.Value) **** End of the sample code

Comment: In the above sample I'm passing values from text box to a existing field in the report. Likewise, you have to pass the values from your dateset to report fields (First insert the report fields manually)